# How to navigate to another page with a smooth scroll on a specific id?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website with multipages .. 
So i need a code for navigating to another page with smooth scrolling after loading on a specific id or section on another page

e.g. in the navbar i have multipages so i will make a page contain 4 links from the navbar .. so i need when i click on the link in the navbar navigate me to the page containing this links and smooth scroll down to the section contains this link i clicked on it

I made't with only html but without the smooth scrolling .. i just click on the link in the navbar and it navigate me to the specified section that contains this link info. in the other page

I don't know if my question is clear enough but i hope so

Comment: You have a goal, how have you tried to get there? Share [mcve] of the problem you are facing.

Comment: about doing it with html only i just gave an id for the section in the other page i need to navigate to and wrote it like this href="otherpage.html#thesection"
so i made it but without the scrolling it's so solid .. so i need a javascript code for doing a scroll when i navigate to this section from another page

Comment: If you need the code, try to code it of find a library that does what you need. This is not a coding service.

Comment: I am just asking for how to do it because i didn't find any solution for this .. so maybe someone know how to do it with a code or just to give me the idea or the first step to walk through it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Modern Browsers detect the *hash* in the url and then automatically open that part. So, if you want to scroll smoothly to that part instead, you first need to reset the *scroll position* to 0 and then add smooth scrolling.

Add the following `script`

```
// direct browser to top right away
if (window.location.hash)
    scroll(0,0);
// takes care of some browsers issue
setTimeout(function(){scroll(0,0);},1);
```

Now, try to access the anchor from other page and you will notice that the browser takes you to top of the page without scrolling to the anchor element.

Now, add smooth scroll:

```
$(function(){
//your current click function
$('.scroll').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop:$($(this).attr('href')).offset().top + 'px'
    },1000,'swing');
});

// if we have anchor on the url (calling from other page)
if(window.location.hash){
    // smooth scroll to the anchor id
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop:$(window.location.hash).offset().top + 'px'
        },1000,'swing');
    }
});
```

It will work perfectly now. You will be taken to the anchor element in other page with scrolling smoothly to that part.

Complete *code*:

```
// direct browser to top right away
if (window.location.hash)
    scroll(0,0);
// takes care of some browsers issue
setTimeout(function(){scroll(0,0);},1);

$(function(){
//your current click function
$('.scroll').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop:$($(this).attr('href')).offset().top + 'px'
    },1000,'swing');
});

// if we have anchor on the url (calling from other page)
if(window.location.hash){
    // smooth scroll to the anchor id
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop:$(window.location.hash).offset().top + 'px'
        },1000,'swing');
    }
});
```

Comment: where do you set that code? in the page with the link or in the page with the anchor?

Comment: Very nice piece of functionality.

Answer (score 5):

In you CSS file Simply add-

```
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

And specify the ID in the href as

href="file_where_the_element_is.html#ID_of_the_element

Eg:

```
<a href="index.html#contentID>
```

Its that SIMPLE!!!
No JS, JQuery required. Only CSS and HTML

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to smooth scrool in $(window).load function rather than $(document).ready as scrolling in $(document).ready may cause it to scroll to wrong position due to wrong offset returned by offset function if images are not yet loaded on page.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.hash) {
        scroll(0, 0);
    }
}

$(window).load(function() {
    if (window.location.hash) {
        const hash = window.location.hash;
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop : $(hash).offset().top
        }, 500);
    }
});
```